# Does the Arrow-Pratt measure of absolute risk aversion have a lower bound with DARA utlity?

Tags: utility, risk-aversion

Say I have the following utility function:

$$u(x,w)=f(w+x)$$

This utility exhibits decreasing absolute risk aversion ($f'>0$, $f''<0$ and $f'''>0$). $x\in R_+$ is the control variable and $w\in R_+$ is an exogenous parameter.

Is there a parametric form of $f$ for which $A(x)>\frac{1}{x}$?

Where $A(x)=\frac{-f''}{f'}$ is the Arrow-Pratt measure of absolute risk-aversion. I cannot manage to find such a function, which makes me believe that maybe the Arrow-Pratt measure has a lower bound when the utility is DARA.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$-\frac{f''}{f'}-\frac 1 x - a = 0 \implies f'' = (-\frac 1x -a ) f'.$$

Set $y\equiv f'$ to arrive at
$$y' = (-\frac 1x -a ) y.$$

This has solution
$$f' = y : \int \frac 1y dy = \int (-\frac 1x -a ) dx$$
$$\implies \ln y = -\ln x -ax \implies y = \frac 1x e^{-ax}.$$

So
$$f' = \frac 1x e^{-ax} \implies f(x) = \int^{ax}_{-\infty}\frac 1t e^{-t}dt.$$

This is related to the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). It satisfies the required inequality for any $a>0$. The lower bound need not be minus infinity, for your purposes.
Explore how you can insert the exogenous parameter $w$ in there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the answer is no. There does not exist a utility function satisfying DARA such that $A(x)>\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\in R_+$.

To prove that, let's assume such a function exists. Then, there must exists $a\in R_+$ such that:
$$\frac{-f''}{f'}>\frac{1}{x}\Leftrightarrow\frac{-f''}{f'}-\frac{1}{x}-a=0$$
If we rearrange this function a bit by taking $y=x+w$, we have:
$$-\frac{f''(y)}{f'(y)}=\frac{1+a(y-w)}{y-w}\qquad\text{(1)}$$
Expression (1) is a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation. Solving it (here pardon my laziness, I used [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5By%27%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cy%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%3DDivide%5B%5C%2840%291-ax%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D)) gives:
$$f(y)=\int_1^{y}exp\bigg(\int_{1}^{\phi}\frac{a(\rho-w)+1}{w-\rho}d\rho\bigg)c_1d\phi+c_2$$
Taking the derivative of $f$ we get:
$$f'(y)=exp\bigg(\int_1^{y}\frac{a(\rho-w)+1}{w-\rho}d\rho\bigg)c_1$$
So we do have the condition $f'>0$ fulfilled as long as $c_1>0$. Taking the second-order derivative of $f$, we get:
$$f''(y)=\frac{a(y-w)+1}{w-y}exp\bigg(\int_1^{y}\frac{a(\rho-w)+1}{w-\rho}d\rho\bigg)c_1$$
This expression is negative if and only if:
$$\frac{a(y-w)+1}{w-y}>0$$
Using the fact that $x=y-w$:
$$-\frac{1+ax}{x}>0\Leftrightarrow x<-\frac{1}{a}$$
We have a contradiction -- if I did not make any mistake in the computations -- there does not exist a DARA utility function where $A(x)>\frac{1}{x}$, for all $x\in R_+$.